# How to configure Xerces2-J to ingore xsi:schemaLocation hints?

Tags: java, xml, xerces, xerces2-j

I am using Xerces2-J and have built a grammar pool as described in the [Grammars FAQ](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-grammars.html#faq-1)

When parsing the document instance, I would like the parser to ignore any xsi:schemaLocation or xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation hints.

The FAQ says

> registering a do-nothing EntityResolver will allow the application to deny validators from using any but the "approved" grammar set.

How is a "do-nothing" entity resolver implemented? The entity resolver needs to implement the [XMLEntityResolver](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xni/org/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLEntityResolver.html) interface, which has one method:

```
public XMLInputSource resolveEntity(XMLResourceIdentifier resourceIdentifier)
    throws XNIException, IOException;
```

Returning `null` will default to the system behavior of trying to resolve the resourceIdentifier.  What return value can be used to simply ignore the resolveEntity request?

Comment: the quote from the FAQ discusses *denying* using anything but the approved grammar set. I take it so that in that case it would throw an exception, so there might not be an option to ignore resolveEntity request. But that's just how I read the quote above, I have no knowledge about it.

Comment: @eis thanks, yes your interpretation makes sense.  From testing, xerces did not attempt to resolveEntity simply from the location hint, but only if a corresponding grammar was not in the grammar pool and also it was actually used in the instance (e.g. an element belonging to the schemaLocation hint namespace).